# PHP Take content between two keys and associate it with one of them

Tags: php

I am trying to arrange a large amount of content into an array based off of a series of array keys. All content after a key needs to be captured and associated with the the key until the next key is hit and the process stars all over.

Example content:

```
Frank
this is some text
this is some more text
this is additional text
Mary
omg some text went here
lawls this text is so silly
ipsum text went here
a fourth line of text goes here
George
a single line of text
Bob
some text with special characters: &dagger;
```

Example Array that I want to compared to the above string

```
array (
    [0] => 'Mary',
    [1] => 'George',
    [2] => 'Bob',
    [3] => 'Frank',
)
```

This is my desired final result:

```
array (
    ['Mary'] => '
        this is some text
        this is some more text
        this is additional text
    ',

    ['George'] => '
        omg some text went here
        lawls this text is so silly
        ipsum text went here
        a fourth line of text goes here
    ',

    ['Bob'] => '
        a single line of text
    ',

    ['Frank'] => '
        some text with special characters: &dagger;
    ',
)
```

---

I've tried the markup below and it kind of works:

It's great that it doesn't depend on an array; but it's not very clean or accurate. The keys are not always wrapped in the same html and the below example is trying to be a catch-all. I'm looking for a way that I can ignore html wrappers like the example above.

```
// Split content into arrays by user
$results = preg_split("(</i>|</div>)", $content);
$results = preg_replace( '#<([^ >]+)[^>]*>([[:space:]]|&nbsp;)*</\1>#', '', $results );

// clean results and remove extra html
foreach($results as $key => $value) {
    $key = strip_tags($key);
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $results[$key] = $value; // strip html tags
    if (strlen($value) > 0 && strlen(trim($value)) == 0) unset($results[$key]); // if array only has spaces in it, remove it
    if (is_null($value) || $value == '' || empty($value)) unset($results[$key]); // if array is empty, remove it
}
```

Comment: So what is your base criterion for splitting the data that way exactly - that those lines are the only ones starting with a capital letter, that they have only one "word" in them, or ...?

Comment: @CBroe  the keywords are in array.

Comment: @CBroe for what I understood the Keys for splitting are in an array.

Comment: It will always be someone's name. Shouldn't ever be two name but it might. One name does return as lowercase.

Comment: So that means you are still using that first array (to have a list of all possible names), or what? If not, then you need to _specify_ what considers a "name".

Comment: _"The keys are not always wrapped in the same html"_ - what HTML? Your example input does not contain _any_ HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in your `$results` are clean strings you provided in the beginning of your question:

```
$names = [];      // your names here
$lookup = [];     // array for new results
$curr_key = '';   // current array key

foreach ($results as $item) {
    if (in_array($item, $names)) {
        /** we met a new name from `$names` 
         * change `$curr_key` and set empty array 
         * with key `$curr_key` in `$lookup`
         */
        $curr_key = $item;
        $lookup[$curr_key] = array();
    } else {
        // just add item to subarray under `$curr_key` key
        $lookup[$curr_key][] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($lookup);
```